# How do i use magic methods from another class?

Tags: python, oop

So I'm trying to use a magic method from one class in another class that inherits that class.
basically what im trying to do below...

```
class Class1:
    def __magicmethod__(self, arg1, arg2):
        #blah blah

class Class2(Class1):
    def func1(self, x, y):
        #what do type here to use the magic method???
```

thank you, I'm really confused about his

Comment: You dont call them directly - you call the wrapping method that will call the magic method. Example:`__eq__` => `==`

Comment: Just call it directly: `c = Class1(); c.__magicmethod__(x, y)`

Comment: @quamrana is there another way to write it like magicmethod( ...)?

Comment: It depends on the actual magic method. You should look up a list of them. Please update your question with a couple of concrete methods you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to transform both comments to a self-contained answer: If `__magicmethod__` is one of the well-known ones with associated operator (like `__eq__` is, simply use the operator to access that. If not, simply "call it directly":

```
class Class1:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print(f"== from {self} with {other} here!")

    def __magicmethod__(self, arg1, arg2):
        print(f"{self}({arg1}, {arg2})")

class Class2(Class1):
    def eq(self, other):
        self == other

    def func1(self, x, y):
        self.__magicmethod__(x, y)
```

And then use like:

```
>> c2 = Class2()
>>> c2.func1("x", "y")
<__main__.Class2 object at 0x0000021B8694A1F0>(x, y)

>>> c2 == "foo"
== from <__main__.Class2 object at 0x0000021B8694A1F0> with foo here!

>>> c2.eq("foo")  # same as before, but through your own method
```

Nothing special really.